# Running the same query with different parameters based on the evaluation of an argument

Tags: t-sql

I have a query containing several parameters.

I need to run the query using one set of parameters if another set of parameters is null.

Is there another way to do this without repeating the statement in a conditional?

For example:

```
USE MYDataBase;
GO

DECLARE @Argument1 VARCHAR = 1234;
DECLARE @Argument2 VARCHAR = 'HELLO WORLD';

IF @Argument1 IS NULL

SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE ColumnValue = @Argument1

ELSE

SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE ColumnValue = @Argument2
```

Are there other ways to run this apart from the method above and putting the query in a proc and calling the proc in the evaluation clause of another statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce:

```
USE MYDataBase;
GO

DECLARE @Argument1 VARCHAR = 1234;
DECLARE @Argument2 VARCHAR = 'HELLO WORLD';

SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE ColumnValue = coalesce(@Argument1, @Argument2)
```

Coalesce will return you the first non-null parameter you provide - or null if all parameters are null.

Comment: Show how will this work if there are for example: 10 parameters on each side? Sorry, I wanted to keep the example simple. Your approach will work well given the simplicity of the example.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you mean by "on each side"..?  If there are many arguments then you just keep adding them: coalesce(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4, ..., ArgN).  Take a look at the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

When you start to get REALLY complex, like 5 or more possibilities I generally use a dynamic statement.

```
create Table DynamicExample (DynamicExampleId int identity, Dsc varchar(32), Memo varchar(512), Memo2 varchar(512))
insert into DynamicExample values ('test', 'Memo', 'Memo2'),('test2', 'Memo 2', 'Memo2 2')

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(512) = 'select * from DynamicExample'

Declare @param nvarchar (128) = ' where {column} = {value}'
declare @column nvarchar(64) = 'DynamicExampleId'
declare @value nvarchar(64) = '2'

Select @param = Replace(@param, '{column}', @column);
Select @param = Replace(@param, '{value}', @value);

Select @SQL += @param

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

The advantage of this is you are not doing this:

If, else, if, else, if, else, if, else, if, else, if, else, etc.  You are literally saying: "If I have predicates determine what they are and their values."  Now saying this if you have multiple predicates you can easily extend a check to see if it's the first predicate or more than the first and extend more with an 'and' instead of 'where'.